# Internet Explorer Crashes on GMail, Youtube and other sites

Tags: website, internet-explorer-8, crash

I have a laptop which runs Windows 7 Home Premium, Internet Explorer V8.0. When I launch IE, it works fine. Sites such as StackOverflow, SuperUser, WebApps.StackExchange, Programmers.StackExchange all work fine.

I launch GMail, enter my credentials and as soon as I am in, IE crashes and attempts to autorecover. It tries the autorecover twice.

The event viewer has the following entry.

> Faulting application name:
>   iexplore.exe, version: 8.0.7600.16385,
>   time stamp: 0x4a5bc69e Faulting module
>   name: Flash10h.ocx, version:
>   10.1.53.64, time stamp: 0x4bfd7406

**ANSWER**

I installed the Windows Updates and it all worked fine now. Thanks people for your answers!

Comment: The mention of sites that work fine (all are StackExchange based products) is purely coincidental. Not because I am hoping for a quick answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go one step further than what @ForceFlow suggested:

1. Close all IE8 screens (heck, go ahead and close everything)
2. From the Install/Uninstall control panel, uninstall the Flash ActiveX
3. Download [Flash Uninstaller](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/141/tn_14157.html) from Adobe. Follow the instructions on the page to completely uninstall Flash
4. Restart
5. Download the [latest Flash version](http://www.filehippo.com/download_flashplayer_ie/) and install

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling flash, then reinstalling the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is because you like IE and want's to keep using it... because otherwise, you could just use Firefox or Chrome. 
I also guess you already tried uninstalling and reinstalling IE.

Maybe it's flash related like the other users commented, but gmail doesn't require Flash to work (it uses it, if present, for only some functionality). So after uninstalling Flash you can try and open gmail again in IE to make sure.

Comment: Yes. I am quite happy with IE 8, although I do use Chrome for Teux Deux. In fact, I did nothing...I installed the Windows 7 Updates (which I had not done for a while) and now IE works fine.